# How to find out the exact issue in Qt

Tags: qt

I installed above qt version 5.5.0 in my host system and created app. Using angstrom cross compiler i cross compiled the created app. After cross compilation i copied the executable using pen drive and paste in `/opt` folder target folder.

If i run like `./MyApp -qws` , it is successfully running but not display anything , because there is no QWS api for Qt version 5.

If i run like `./MyApp -platform eglfs` , I get the error like `QWSSocket::connectToLocalFile could not connect:: Connection refused` .

How to find out exact problem and resolve it?

Comment: use Qt4 instead of Qt5

Comment: Actually im using Qt creator to develop application. Qt creator version is 3.4.2 (opensource) but it based on Qt 5.5.0 (GCC 4.9.1 20140922 (Red Hat 4.9.1-10), 64 bit) . where to refer which qt creator version having less than Qt5 included

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Angstrom cross compiler works well and the application is not displaying because im not exporting the command such as **export QT_ONSCREEN_PAINT=force**